# How to change the voice recognition to french (always try to speak in english in twilio)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, voice, twilio-twiml

How to change the voice recognition to french (always try to speak in english in twilio). It work well in voiceflow but in twilio the system always try to make english word but I want it to make french word not english thank you

I try to change the language in the option but no success

Comment: Can you share some code of a minimal example to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code, you can change the languages like so:

```
<Response>
<Say language="fr-FR" voice="Polly.Lea-Neural">Speak in French!</Say>
</Response>
```

If you are using the Console, you can refer to the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#language-mapping

**[All Supported French Voices](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#language-mapping:%7E:text=French%20(Canada),FR%2DNeural2%2DE)**